# XMLElement with tags in between String

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsxmlelement

I am creating a XML document and trying to insert tags in between XMLElement as below

```
let tEle = XMLElement.element(withName: "xuv") as? XMLElement
let segEle = XMLElement.element(withName: "seg") as? XMLElement
segEle?.stringValue = "Sample Text Here"
tuvEle?.addChild(segEle!)
```

This is working fine, but for segEle i want to add some tags between text as `"Sample Text <ph x="1" type="x-LPH"/> Here"`, if we notice i need to insert "ph" tag in between the string.

FYI : I tried to insert `" <ph x=\"#\" type=\"x-LPH\"/> "` this text between string but this didn't worked as in the output xml file the `"ph"` tag is displayed as `&lt;ph x="0" type="x-LPH"/&gt; OBLIGATOIRE &lt;ph x="1" type="x-LPH"/&gt;`  (if we notice for "<" it is replaced as "<" and for ">" is replaced as">")

Can anyone please let me know how can we handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to backwards-engineer how it's supposed to be: inspect the result of `XMLElement(xmlString: "<seg>Sample Text <ph x=\"1\" /> Here")` and its children.

```
Sample Text <element/> Here
^^^^^^^^^^^^~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^
    |          |         |
    |          |         --------- Text node
    |          |
    |          ----- XMLElement
    |
    ----------- Text node
```

- `XMLElement` is only suitable for tags;
- `XMLElement.addChild` accepts the more general type `XMLNode`.
- `XMLNode.Kind` can be `.text`, which is what you're looking for instead of the simpler `stringValue`.

So you have to split your simple string value into 3 subnodes:

1. `XMLNode.text(withStringValue: "Sample Text ") as? XMLNode`
2. `XMLNode.element(withName: "Sample Text ") as? XMLElement`
3. `XMLNode.text(withStringValue: " Here") as? XMLNode`

Then add all 3 children to the parent note `segEle` (which doesn't need a `stringValue` anymore).

Comment: Nice Answer @ctietze , I did tried this and it is working fine. Only issue is the 3rd child is displaying in new line, but all the 3 children should be in same line.
it is displaying as below as of now in multiple lines, i need to print "here</seg>" in the same line as others.

<seg>Sample Text<PH></PH>
                    here</seg>

Comment: Could this be an issue of the string output? How do you produce the string, `canonicalXMLStringPreservingComments(Bool)` for the `segEle`? (Best if you expand your question by adding this detail.)

Comment: thanks again for your answer. Sorry for my previous question. It is not an issue if the 3rd child is in next line or in the same line, as when i tried to print it, they always print in the same line.

Thanks again, marking this as an answer as it did helped me.

Comment: Ah well, maybe it's best to open a different question, with all the nodes set up in the example code of the question, asking how to modify the resulting printed string?